# OpenRowSet returning only one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, import-from-excel, openrowset

I am using OPENROWSET and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to retrieve data in SSMS from an Excel 2007 (.xlsx) file. When I execute the query I only get the title of the first column (Excel cell A1) and F2, F3, etc. for the rest of the columns and no data within the table. The Excel file contains data; however, OPENROWSET is not retrieving anything other than cell A1.

I have tried both

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\filepath.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\filepath.xlsx',[Sheet1$])
```

I get the same result for both queries.

I have also tried using the Import/Export Wizard (64-bit) and when I am on the 'Select Source Tables and Views' and use Edit Mappings... I receive the following error:

```
Column information for the source and destination data could not be retrieved

-Unexpected error from external database driver(1).
**Additional information**
->Unexpected error from external database driver (1).(Microsoft Access Database Engine)
```

I have a 64-bit version of SQL Server that is being used. Also, this is an Excel file that I receive from an outside source. The other Excel files I receive from outside sources do not give me any problems when retrieving data using the same method. Additionally, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and the Excel file is located on the same drive as the SQL Server.

Any help is greatly appreciated. It would be nice if I could get this working so I can handle moving the data from these files over to a SSIS package.

Comment: ACE can make some strange assumptions about the layout of your excel file when trying to convert into something that can be queried (especially with data types. OMG don't get me started on that one). Anyway, take a look at the xls file in excel. If there is a blank row between the header and the start of the data, that can cause problems. Also a null column that seperates the data down the middle. Generally ACE will analyze the first 8 or so rows to determine what it cares about so those first 8 need to be in tip top shape.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Every cell in a 26 x 129 grid has some sort of data in the fields on the .xlsx file. There's no nulls or empty rows between any of the data. I just tried something I didn't think about earlier, and I opened the file and Save As. The query works fine without any issues when re-saved. Do you by any chance know what would be causing the file to keep ACE from correctly reading it?

Comment: Have any body got solution for this issue?
Because on re saving in Excel (office) the OPENROWSET returns correct result.